# Can't I use <a> tags in XML to refer to a specific <div> section?

Tags: html, css, xml

For example: I want to jump to the section where  when clicking on 'Next'.
I used the code below but it is not working.

```
<a href="#container-item2">Next</a>
```

Comment: There is no code attached. Incomplete question.

Comment: Tab in your code with 4 spaces for it to be readable.

Comment: @Coder111, I totally overlooked the XML specific in the title. I removed my answer as it was not relevant. Sorry, I haven't dealt with XML, so I'm of no help.

Comment: Something tells me this question isn't what it seems... div sections *in XML*? Is there an XML fragment involved in an HTML page, or is this an XML document?

Comment: XML is basically a framework to define your own data formats. It doesn't have anything to do with HTML or CSS unless you have an application that makes use of XML to manipulate either. Without that information it's impossible to determine what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in XML. But you need to tell the browser that the `<a>` element is in the html namespace, so that it knows that it is a link. You do so by including the attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

E.g. you can do this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="data:text/css,foo * {display:block; margin: 1em 0} foo {width:300px; font-size:1.3em} baz {color:red}"?>
<foo>
  <a href="#container-item2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Jump to container item 2</a>
  <bar>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</bar>
  <bar>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</bar>
  <bar>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</bar>
  <baz id="container-item2">This is Container Item 2</baz>
  <bar>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</bar>
  <bar>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</bar>
  <bar>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</bar>
</foo>
```

See http://alohci.net/static/xml-link-target.xml

This works in modern Chrome, Firefox and Edge but not in IE. Haven't tested others.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.